# SQL Left Join a Table on a Left Joined Table

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam currently trying to left join a table on a left joined table as follows.
I have the tables:

- accounts (id, vorname, nachname)
- projektkurse (id, accounts_id, projektwochen_id)
- projektkurs_einzel (id, projektkurse_id)
- projektkurs_einzel_zeiten (id, date, shift, projektkurs_einzel_id)

Now I want to get every account and the amount times they have an entry inside of projektkurs_einzel_zeiten, which should also be unique. So having the same date and shift multiple times does not count as multiple entries. The result should also be limited by the column projektwochen_id from the table projektkurse. This column should match a certain value for example 8.

Some Accounts don't have any entries in projektkurse, projektkurs_einzel and projektkurs_einzel_zeiten, this is why my first thought was using LEFT JOIN like this:

```sql
SELECT accounts.id, accounts.vorname, accounts.nachname, COUNT(DISTINCT projektkurs_einzel_zeiten.date, projektkurs_einzel_zeiten.shift) AS T
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN projektkurse on accounts.id = projektkurse.creator_id
LEFT JOIN projektkurs_einzel on projektkurse.id = projektkurs_einzel.projektkurs_id
LEFT JOIN projektkurs_einzel_zeiten ON projektkurs_einzel.id = projektkurs_einzel_zeiten.projektkurs_einzel_id
WHERE projektkurse.projektwochen_id = 8
GROUP BY accounts.id
```

This query does not achieve exactly what I want. It only returns accounts that have atleast one entry in projektkurse even if they have none in projektkurs_einzel and projektkurs_einzel_zeiten. The Count is obviously 0 for them but the accounts that have no entries in projektkurse are being ignored completly.
How can I also show the accounts that don't have entries in any other table with the Count 0 aswell?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help!

Comment: Keep in mind your query might be invalid to be used see [MySQL GROUP BY handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use eft join table's column ins where condition  this work as inner join

You should move the where condition for a left joined  table  in the corresponding ON clause

```
SELECT accounts.id, accounts.vorname, accounts.nachname, COUNT(DISTINCT projektkurs_einzel_zeiten.date, projektkurs_einzel_zeiten.shift) AS T
FROM accounts
LEFT JOIN projektkurse on accounts.id = projektkurse.creator_id 
                          AND projektkurse.projektwochen_id = 8
LEFT JOIN projektkurs_einzel on projektkurse.id = projektkurs_einzel.projektkurs_id
LEFT JOIN projektkurs_einzel_zeiten ON projektkurs_einzel.id = projektkurs_einzel_zeiten.projektkurs_einzel_id
GROUP BY accounts.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing the query like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.vorname, a.nachname,
       COUNT(DISTINCT pez.date, pez.shift) AS T
FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN
     projektkurse 
     ON a.id = pk.creator_id AND
        pk.projektwochen_id = 8 LEFT JOIN
     projektkurs_einzel pe
     ON pk.id = pe.projektkurs_id LEFT JOIN
     projektkurs_einzel_zeiten pez
     ON pe.id = pez.projektkurs_einzel_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.vorname, a.nachname;
```

Notes:

- Your problem is fixed by moving the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause.  Your `WHERE` turns the outer join into an inner join, because `NULL` values do not match.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- It is a best practice to include all unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.  However, assuming that `id` is unique, your formulation is okay (due to something called "functional dependencies").

Comment: *" (and required by the default settings of the most recent releases of MySQL)."* Not totally true as MySQL 5.7.5 + supports  functionally dependency with sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY setting just fine, see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) page *"It is a best practice to include all unaggregated columns in the GROUP BY"* That can i agree on as not every database vender is supporting the functionally dependency which is optional in the SQL standard.. Still +1

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . In that case, thank you for your patience.